# Android: Quiz-App in different languages - Can't get the questions from string-array

Tags: android

I'm developing a Quiz app for Android. At first I simply had my questions and possible answers in an array, like:

```
public String[][] questions = {
    {"Question1", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4"},
    {"Question2", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4"},
    ...
```

This array is in my QuizActivity.java and it worked fine. But I want that Quiz for different languages (at least 2), so I need the questions and the choices in different languages. From what I found arrays.xml (or strings.xml) is used for this. So I created arrays.xml in my values directory. This file
looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="q1">
        <item>Question1</item>
        <item>Choice1</item>
        <item>Choice2</item>
        <item>Choice3</item>
        <item>Choice4</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="q2">
        <item>Question2</item>
        <item>Choice1</item>
        <item>Choice2</item>
        <item>Choice3</item>
        <item>Choice4</item>
    </string-array>
...
</resources>
```

In my QuizActivity.java I changed the array to

```
  public String[][] questions = {
       getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q1),
       getResources().getStringArray(R.array.q2),
       ...
```

Now, if I start this activity, the app crashes and I get the following error code:
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"

I thought this wouldn't be a problem because I used getResources() from within an Activity.

So my first question is: What's wrong with the above code?
Second question: Are there easier options for what I want to do, especially if I have hundreds of questions? The only requirement is that it should work in different languages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, just a few minutes after I posted this questions I came up with ths solution myself: The above code was in an Activity, but outside the onCreate() method. I moved it to onCreate() and now it works fine...

But question 2 remains: Are there easier ways to do this and could this lead to problems if I have a lot of questions?